# Populating listbox with sqldata one by one from remoting server

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I'm actually populating a `ListBox` with sqldata, and it's working, except the data only appears once the request is over. I've been trying to use threads here, but I'm getting lost on how I could achieve this. 
I've also tried to do a `for` loop which does load one by one the data in my `ListBox`, but it's taking ages to load all the data, and I don't want that.

Here is how I populate my `ListBox` :

```
internal delegate void SetDataSourceDelegate(List<DataDerogationObjects.DerogationUPRArgs> list);
private void setDataToList(List<DataDerogationObjects.DerogationUPRArgs> list)
{
   if (pgDerog.wrapItemControl.Dispatcher.Thread == Thread.CurrentThread)
   {
      pgDerog.wrapItemControl.ItemsSource = list.Select(x => x.derogation);
   }
   else
   {
      pgDerog.wrapItemControl.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new SetDataSourceDelegate(setDataToList), list);
   }

}
```

And here is how I'm calling it :

```
//Some code...

Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(loadData));
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.Start();

//Some code...

void loadData()
{
   List<DataDerogationObjects.DerogationUPRArgs> tmpList = new List<DataDerogationObjects.DerogationUPRArgs>();
   tmpList = iDerog.listDerogation(); // This is my sql which return a list of DataDerogationObjects.DerogationUPRArgs
   setDataToList(tmpList);
}
```

And here is what my `DataDerogationObjects.DerogationUPRArgs` looks like

```
[Serializable]
public class DerogationUPRArgs : EventArgs
{
   public DerogationRecord derogation { get; set; }
   public int totalNumber { get; set; }
   public int actualNumber { get; set; }
}
```

`DerogationRecord` is a class which contains informations such as `id`, `name`, etc.
Feel free to ask for more information. Thanks !

[EDIT]

```
public List<DataDerogationObjects.DerogationUPRArgs> listDerogation()
{
   List<DataDerogationObjects.DerogationUPRArgs> returnList = new List<DataDerogationObjects.DerogationUPRArgs>();
   OleDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
   command.CommandText = "select distinct QuotaCarte.IDCarteQuota, Nom , CodePostal, maxQtType1, maxQtType2, maxQtType3, maxQtType4, maxQtType5, DateValidité, idCarteJointe1, QtType1, QtType2, QtType3, QtType4, QtType5, dateCreation, CategorieClient, UCASE(Nom) from quotaCarte " +
                "left join QuotaCarteExtend on QuotaCarte.IDCarteQuota = QuotaCarteExtend.IDCarteQuota where substring(QuotaCarte.IDcarteQuota, 1,6) = '900000' order by UCASE(Nom)";
   int total = CountDBRecord(), count = 0;

   OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.SingleResult);
   while (reader.Read())
   {
      object[] tableau = new object[20];
      reader.GetValues(tableau);
      DataDerogationObjects.DerogationUPRArgs readed = new DataDerogationObjects.DerogationUPRArgs();
      readed.derogation = ConvertReadedObjectTableToDerogationRecord(tableau);
      count++;
      readed.totalNumber = total;
      readed.actualNumber = count;

      returnList.Add(readed);

   }
   return returnList;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Task to achieve what you want.

```
TaskScheduler uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
```

This allows you to update the View from a thread that not the UI thread.

Then you have to pass it to the Task constructor:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew( () => 
  {
 // here you should update your listbox with the item you want...do the process where you get and update the listbox.
  }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, uiScheduler);
```

Any doubts just "shoot out" :)

Comment: Where should I use it ? In my `setDataList` in my `if` ?

Comment: that is the part i did not understand in your code. iDerog.listDerogation(); fetches all info right? then you want what? to loop through and add element by element right?

Comment: iDerog.listDerogation() actually get all the data from my database. And this is where I'm stuck, I'd like to update my ListBox while I'm loading my data. But I can't do it in my iDerog.listDerogation().

Comment: the only way you have is to change the listDerogation() method. It's the only place where you have the info. Can you show the code in that method?

Comment: Edited with listDerogation() method.

Comment: Ok. that's best, one last question, can you have the itemssource binded in the XAML?

Comment: No, I can't. I have to do it programmaticaly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50872/discussion-between-sexta13-and-hyarantar)